# Arithmetic in the return statement cause unexpected behavior

Tags: php

I'm currently learning PHP from a HTML, CSS, and JS background and I came across some unexpected behavior that interested me. Consequently, I experimented with the following code.

## Experiment 1:

It seems that when written the return statement is written like this, everything before the arithmetic is removed/not rendered.

*Code:*

```
<?php
    function add($num, $num2) {
      return $num."+".$num2." = ".$num + $num2."<br>";
    }
    
    echo add(10, 7) . add(20, 1);
?>
```

*Outputs*:

```
17<br>
21<br>
```

## Experiment 2:

However, when I change the first variable/parameter from `$num` to `$num2`, it seems that every between the first variable and the `+` operator is removed.

*Code:*

```
<?php
    function add($num, $num2) {
      return $num2."+".$num2." = ".$num + $num2."<br>";
    }
    
    echo add(10, 7) . add(20, 1);
?>
```

*Outputs*:

```
14<br>
2<br>
```

## Experiment 3:

After [trying](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/c0c5dqsa/) it in JS, I realized that putting brackets around the arithmetic equation would output the expected result.

*Code:*

```
<?php
    function add($num, $num2) {
      return $num."+".$num2." = ".($num + $num2)."<br>";
    }
    
    echo add(10, 7) . add(20, 1);
?>
```

*Outputs*:

```
10+7 = 17<br>
20+1 = 21<br>
```

(Also making a `$sum` variable would fix the problem)

## Question:

My question is what causes the unexpected behavior by not putting the brackets around the equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is the result of "type juggling".

Because PHP is not strictly-typed, a string can be interpreted as an integer when needed (or assumed to be needed by the interpreter), or vice versa. So the data type is converted, and if you're not careful can cause issues. In many other languages you would get an error if you treated a string like an integer or an integer like a string. JavaScript, for example, has `String.parseInt()` to explicitly change the type.

What the interpreter is doing is roughly the following, step-by-step:

1. `$num` - establish an integer with value `10`
2. `10."+"` - concatenating an integer with a string

   - Convert the current output to a string (`10` becomes `"10"`), and append a plus sign
   - Output is now `"10+"`
3. `"10+".$num2` - concatenating a string with an integer

   - Convert the integer to a string and append it
   - Output is now `"10+7"`
4. `"10+7"." = "` - concatenating 2 strings

   - Output is now `"10+7 = "`
5. `"10+7 = ".$num` - concatenating a string with an integer

   - Convert the integer to a string and append it
   - Output is now `"10+7 = 10`
6. `"10+7 = 10" + $num2` - arithmetic calculation between a string and an integer

   - Convert the string to an integer and add it to the next integer.
   - In this case, when PHP converts a string to an integer, it starts at the beginning of the string and returns all numerals until it hits the first non-number, so `"10+7 = 10"` pulls out the 10, then hits the `+` and stops looking for numbers.
   - Output is now `17`;
7. `17."<br>"` - concatenation of an integer and a string

   - Convert the integer to a string and append the `<br>`
   - Output is now `17<br>`.

For reference:

- Documentation on type juggling: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Happy to be of service. PHP has a lot of detractors for reasons that range from nitpicky to genuine issues. The fact that its so loose with data types, for me, is a genuine issue to complain about, and trips a lot of people up. Just be sure to be explicit with your intentions in code and it should be fine. Oh, and unit test. Lets you test out all kinds of scenarios to see if your code meets your expectations.

Answer (score 2):

How does PHP know that you don't want to take this `$num."+".$num2." = ".$num` and arithmetically add it to this `$num2."<br>"`?  It doesn't, unless you use parentheses to cause the `$num + $num2` to happen first.

In the first example:

```
$num."+".$num2." = ".$num
```

Equates to the string: `10+7=10`, and then:

```
$num2
```

Equates to `7`.

When you attempt to add them `+` the string `10+7=10` must be cast to an integer `10` and  and when added to `7` gives you `17` then the string `<br>` is concatenated.

See [PHP: String Conversion to Numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

With parentheses:

```
$num."+".$num2." = ".($num + $num2)."<br>";
```

You get string `10+7=` concatenated with `10+7` (`17`) concatenated with string `<br>`.

Comment: Great explanation. Here is a [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) for all operators, which shows why multiplication works as OP expected, but addition doesn't.

Comment: '7 + 7' + 7 .<br> = 7 + 7 . '<br>' = 14 . '<br>' = '14<br>'. You used num2 twice. The rest is just like AbraCadaver explained